# MySQL/PHP - Getting differents rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Alright, so I have a database, each with an ID, a name and a textvalue.

I wish to be able to print each of a specific row individually. When I use

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable", $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['text'];
```

I am only able to print the first row, as it doesn't select any specifics. The problem is, I'm not sure how to use the WHERE ID='X', as I want the first one to print the first column, the second to print the second column and so forth (there are a total of 13 lines). I want to echo them on different places on the page, so just calling everything at once is not what I'm looking for.

The way things are now, I'll have to use the code above for each time I want to print it, and manually edit the WHERE ID='1' on the first print, the second to WHERE ID='2' and so on, which is rather a pain in the ass.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: The mysql_functions are depreciated. You should use mysqli_ instead (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or, better yet, PDO.

Comment: can you write the name of your database columns

Comment: The columns are "ID", "name", "text". I wish to extract the information in "text" where ID is 1, 2, 3 and so forth, but echo them on separate places in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM mytable WHERE ID > 0 AND ID < 5", $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo $i . ' - ' . $row[0] . '<br/>';  
$i++
}
```

If you want 4 variables with the text to use in differents part of your code then use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM mytable WHERE ID > 0 AND ID < 5", $db);

$var1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
echo $var1[0];

$var2 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
echo $var2[0];

$var3 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
echo $var3[0];

$var4 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
echo $var4[0];
```

Comment: @Eirik Guldbrandsen don't forget check the answer as correct

Answer (score 4):

Keep calling `mysql_fetch_array` until it returns null:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result ))
{
   echo $row['text'] . '<br/>';
}
```

This is shown in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), which also will tell you this:

> **Warning**
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: While appreciated, this is not the solution I'm looking for, as this puts all into a single echo. I should have been more specific, but I want to echo the different rows in different places.

Comment: Then you need to store the rows in another data structure (or the ouput created with those rows) or loop over the result set in each one of those places.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to iterate through all records.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM mytable", $db);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    echo $row['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using a more object-oriented approach:

1) setup a PDO object like this:

```
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'yourDbUsername';
$dbpass = 'yourDbPassword';
$dbname = 'databaseName';

$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$dbAdapter = new PDO($dsn,$dbuser,$dbpass);
$dbAdapter->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbAdapter->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

2) use PDO objects to run queries and fetch result sets:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable';
$statementObject = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
$resultSet = $statementObject->fetchAll();
```

3) iterate over the resulting array:

```
foreach($resultSet as $row){
    echo $row['text'] . "<br />";
}
```